# Select condition on date for datetime field

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I want to impose date condition on a date time field in SQL Server.

The `datetime` field is like this `2011-01-19 17:57:18.350` and when I execute below query it yields no results.

```
select top 1000 * 
from [dbo].[RouteState] 
where convert (date, logtime, 101) = '12-01-2015'
```

Can someone help me what's going wrong here?

Comment: I think 101 returns date in yyyy-MM-dd whereas you are comparing with dd-MM-YYYY

Comment: Hi Nasir, Do you think it 121?

Comment: Ah.. Its 105 and I got some results too..

Comment: your syntax is a bit wrong 'SELECT convert (varchar(12),getdate(),101)' and for formats you can see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to convert the `datetime` column to anything. Use a closed-open interval instead and change the format of your string literal to `yyyymmmdd` to make sure that SQL Server will interpret the date value in the same way regardless of regional and date format settings.

```
select top 1000 * 
from [dbo].[RouteState] 
where logtime >= '20150112' and
      logtime < '20150113';
```

For more info on casting a column to date you can have a look at [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)